# getLineIn() in Minim doesn't work with Processing

Tags: java, processing, minim

## Problem

I'm trying Minim with Processing.

I tried [MonitorInput.pde](https://github.com/ddf/Minim/blob/master/examples/Basics/MonitorInput/MonitorInput.pde) and [other samples](https://qiita.com/Beef1297/items/80c2cc080601f4127812) I found on the internet but getLineIn() doesn't work no matter how big sound. However, the console shows me no errors.

## Because of Catalina?

I use macOS Catalina version 10.15.4. The other user said he got the same problem with Catalina but he succeeded with High Sierra. So I'm guessing this is caused by the stricter permissions of Catalina.

I checked the permission of the microphone in System Preferences, but there is no Java and I don't know how to add it.

## Environment

- macOS Catalina version 10.15.4
- I tried samples on IDE and Visual Studio Code, with a built-in microphone and an external microphone.

Comment: You mention that you've 'tried your sample' - If you have some code that you could post to show what you've tried it would help people a lot when working out an answer to the question.

Comment: thanks, I added the link of the sample I tried.

Comment: @TakayaOgawa I would try to isolate the issue: 1. can you record from the same audio input source using Audacity or something similar (double checking the expected device has *use this device for sound input* enabled in Audio MIDI Setup) ? If so, then it's a java sound library issue, otherwise it's an OSX audio/ driver configuration issue. 2. If recording in Audacity works, try different different audio libraries like [Beads](http://beadsproject.net/) or [processing.sound](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/sound/Amplitude.html) (and check for errors). If those work you can choose...

Comment: ...if you beads or processing do what you need and you want to switch otherwise, if it's imperative to use Minim, call `minim.debugOn();` in setup, look at the console and start debugging/isolating the reason why minim isn't happy accessint the audio input and returning the data you're after. HTH